# Comparing Two JSON Files In O(n)

Tags: python, json, complexity, dictionary

I've got a scenario where I need to compare two JSON files and override one if the values are different. These JSONs also include arrays (i.e. `[`)

My approach is to traverse one JSON to dictionary O(n), and then traverse the second JSON against the dictionary (also O(n)??).

There by getting 2O(n) ~ O(n).

Am I day dreaming? Or is there more efficient approach for such problem (or possibly something similar)?

EDIT:

- Both files have the same structure, format and order. The only difference is key value.
- I can share the code I've now, if you feel this is appropriate forum.

Comment: If you find a difference, what happens? Do you always pick the value (for example) from file A? Then why don't you simply copy A to B wholesale in the first place?

Comment: @KilianFoth thank you for the comment. To add a bit, both files have identical structure and keys, but the values may differ.

Comment: @KilianFoth you are right, copying A to B would be much easier, but as a learning experience I'm interested to know what's an efficient way to do so.

Comment: What is the point of translating one JSON file to a dictionary first? Why not comparing the data of the JSON files directly?

Comment: @JanDotNet how can you compare the files directly and point out the diffs? Specifically, a nested JSON dict will output the whole dict.

Comment: In .net there is a [JsonTextReader](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJsonWithJsonTextReader.htm). I am not familiar with python, but most likely there is a similar mechanism to iterate directly over JSON files.

Comment: @Simply_me: using readers to iterate directly over files without loading the whole file in memory seems not that common in python. Therefore, just ignore my comment ;)

Comment: @JanDotNet: JSON files are considered equal if parsing them gives the same result. There are trivial differences like whitespace. Strings can have different escaped characters. One can be UTF-8 and one little-endian UTF-32. But worst, dictionaries can be in arbitrary order.

Comment: how big is the data and how often is the compare function being called? If it's only a few dozen (or hundreds, or thousands) of lines, performance probably isn't going to matter much. Are you certain that performance is a concern here?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, yes: doing two O(n) things results in another O(n) operation. Constant terms or even factors such as "two" or even "seventeen" don't count in this calculus.

Second, well, if you really need to compare every value in both structures, then you obviously can't do any better than accessing each at least once, so there's no point worrying how to get a faster solution than that.

But more generally, what the best solution is depends on what exactly the requirements are. Do you have to find out *whether* the two are different, or *how* they differ, or do you also have to *write* one of the two do *make* them equal?

Finding out whether the two are different means that you can stop once you've found the first difference. That's still an O(n) operation, but it might save considerable time nevertheless. If you have to compile a list of differences, then obviously you can't take that short cut. And if you have to *write* one file, then that will probably take much more time than whatever operations you can program on the contents (disk I/O is *tremendously* slower than memory operations), so you're probably better off simply copying one file to the other. (In fact, most file systems *only* allow you to write out an entire file, so you'd have to pay for the entire write anyway, even if you have a list of specific differences to process.)

Comment: thank you for the answer. I would like to keep it at linear time, not faster :-). Right now I'm reading one file to dicts, and working on comparing the key-Val pairs.